# Empty space when scrolling in uiwebviews

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, scroll

[image: problem when scrolling a page in uiwebviews]

I'm looking for a way to block the page from scrolling too far, leaving an empty grey when going too far from where it should stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set like this

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Comment: webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled might not let me scroll the page, right ?

Comment: @Ben Then you can set bounces = NO;